# jQuery validation to select at least one checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox

I have written following code to select multiple checkbox and also need to validate at least one checkbox is selected. In the following code data submission to database is working if I remove `onsubmit="return validate_form()"`. But I want to validate at least one checkbox is selected.

Following is the code:

```
<?php
$link=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("cant connect");

mysql_select_db("country_ajax",$link) or die("cant select db");
extract($_POST);
$check_exist_qry="select * from language";
$run_qry=mysql_query($check_exist_qry);
$total_found=mysql_num_rows($run_qry);
if($total_found >0)
{
    $my_value=mysql_fetch_assoc($run_qry);
    $my_stored_language=explode(',',$my_value['language_name']);
}

if(isset($submit))
{
    $fname=$_POST['fname'];
    $sname=$_POST['sname'];
    $all_language_value = implode(",",$_POST['language']);
    if($total_found >0)
    {
        //update
        $upd_qry="UPDATE language SET language_name='".$all_language_value."' where member_id = 75";
        mysql_query($upd_qry);

    }
    else
    {
        //insert
        $ins_qry="INSERT INTO language(language_name) VALUES('".$all_language_value."') where member_id = 75";
        mysql_query($ins_qry);
    }
}

?>
<form method="post" action="" onsubmit="return validate_form()";>
<input type="text" name="fname"/><br>
<input type="text" name="sname"/><br>
languahe you know <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="language[]" value="1" <?php if(in_array(1,$my_stored_language)){echo "checked";}?>><label>PHP</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="language[]" value="2" <?php if(in_array(2,$my_stored_language)){echo "checked";}?>><label>Java</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="language[]" value="3" <?php if(in_array(3,$my_stored_language)){echo "checked";}?>><label>c</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="language[]" value="4" <?php if(in_array(4,$my_stored_language)){echo "checked";}?>><label>javascript</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="language[]" value="5" <?php if(in_array(5,$my_stored_language)){echo "checked";}?>><label>c#</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="language[]" value="6" <?php if(in_array(6,$my_stored_language)){echo "checked";}?>><label>.net</label><br>


    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<script>
function validate_form()
{
valid = true;

if($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length == 0)
{
    alert ( "ERROR! Please select at least one checkbox" );
    valid = false;
}

return valid;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Did you include jQuery in your page... is there any console error in your browser

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/syet0jaf/1/ - looks fine - make sure you have jQuery added you your page like `<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>`

Answer (score 2):

```
    function validate_form()
    {
    valid = true;
    $('form').find('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
        if($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length == 0)
        {
            alert ( "ERROR! Please select at least one checkbox" );
            valid = false;
        }
     )};


return valid;
}
```

Try this one.